# Exception thrown in YUI: "Sizzle" is not defined!

Tags: javascript, yui, htmlunit, sizzle

We are using HTML Unit v2.6 with Web-Harvest and extended its functionality to create a new  element

```
<web session="sess1" browser="firefox2">
<web-getpage url="https://www.linkedin.com/secure/login"/>
<web-setinput name="uname">username</web-setinput>
<web-setinput name="pwd">password</web-setinput>
<web-clickinput name="login"/>
</web>
```

When we run this we get an exception while the  element loads the URL specified. The details are as below:

Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function hasOwnProperty in object net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Sizzle" is not defined.
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3651)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3629)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3657)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3676)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3740)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2249)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2216)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1501)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:845)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:164)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:427)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:263)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3058)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:175)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$5.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:415)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:520)
... 42 more

As it appears that 'Sizzle' (present in YUI3) is causing this. We then checked the same in Firefox and IE but neither of the browsers showed any error of 'Sizzle' not being defined.

Also we tried to use latest snapshot of htmlunit, but had same issue.

Is this a limitation(bug) of HTML Unit JavaScript engine?

OR

Is there anyway to configure HTML Unit to handle this exception?

If anyone has already had such an issue, please do let us know.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Sizzle is jQuery's selector engine.  It is not included in YUI 3.

Comment: Thanks Luke, but I don't have control over YUI version. I need to confirm where the issue resides and if anyone has resolved it, how? Please... anybody!